# Cocoapods: how to create own pods for 3rd party library?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoapods

I am using Cocoapods, and one of the libraries I use is ZUUIRevealController, currently the version is 0.9.6 in Cocoapods, which is not the latest one, if I want to create my own pods for that, what are the steps for doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To update for everyone:

OK, so all the cocoapods are held inside a big specs repository [Here](https://github.com/cocoaPods/Specs/). We want to go down to the [ZUUIRevealController](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/ZUUIRevealController) part of the repo. We can see just the 0.9.6 which is how cocoapods knows what version it is.

So, fork the cocoa pods spec repository and open the folder in SublimeMate Pro. You're going to want to add the next version to this folder, so let's say you were going to use 0.9.7. Make a folder for that and copy it over ZUUIRevealController.podspec from version 0.9.6.

The new podspec will need some changing as it refers to the git tag  "v0.9.6" and ideally you want to use 0.9.7. Now I've checked for you, there isn't a 0.9.7 which means you'll have to create an issue asking for a new tag, which [someone has already done.](https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController/issues/66)

With the new tag in the repo you can move that tag into your podfile. Then in the Specs directory run `pod specs lint ZUUIRevealController` which will tell you whether your podspec has passed or failed linting. If you don't do this it will be done automatically on your pull request, and it's likely that it will be me telling you how to fix it.

If it passes, you can then commit that change and submit a pull request to the [Cocoapods/Specs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/) repo on github.

### To update for just you:

in your podspec, you can set the commit that you want to override the normal podfile's commit with ( for example )

`pod 'ZUUIRevealController', :git => 'git://github.com/orta/ZUUIRevealController', :commit => 'd4c9d810e0f0d1982472c8d1d5469841b09854ab'`

This may require deleting your `Pods` directory first as it might have cached the url / commit.

Comment: This only works if the git repo contains the podspec. I wish there was a way to do this for repos that have podspecs only in Cocoapods.